# Inherit NSObjectProtocol with swiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, model-view-controller, swiftui

I am transition a project from ViewController/Storyboard to swiftUI.

The ViewController was implementing a protocol, and therefore inheriting from NSObjectProtocol.

In [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui), there is no ViewController, but there is a ContentView, which is a struct. This cannot inherit from NSObjectProtocol.

In the "old" way, I needed to use the Model/View/Controller design patterm. Should I still do that with swiftUI ? If so, from its name, it seems that ContentView should be just the view, and I am lacking a controller. What's the recommended way of adding the Controller, which could be a class inheriting from [NSObjectProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol)?

Comment: *Should I still do that with swiftUI ?* - No. Apple considers MVVM as native pattern for SwiftUI (WWDC 2019). Btw, I'd say that transition is a bit early, moreover, for macOS.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Can you elaborate on why it is early? Is swiftUI not stable yet?

Comment: No, it is stable, however has enough bugs yet, and still very limited comparing to AppKit/UIKit and more iOS oriented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern for your case is to use the `@StateObject` property wrapper.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var protocolConformer = ObjectiveCProtocolConformer()

    var body: some View {
        // bind UI properties/actions to protocolConformer
    }
}
```

`@StateObject` attaches the given instance to the View corresponding to your declaration, so every time `MyView` is rendered on screen, it will use the same instance of `protocolConformer`.